# Show jqGrid data from two consecutive related database tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

I have this scenario:

One database table `A`, that shows all its data in a `jqGrid`.
For one column of this table, I have a foreign key that references to another database table `B`.
I've setted relation between `A` and `B` and it's showed perfectly in `jqGrid` too. Everything work fine.

The problem is:
I have other column that is a foreign key referenced to table `B`. But the thing that I need is to show another foreign key that is in `B` referencing to other table `C`. I have been able to show that results in `jqGrid` using (badly) `formatter: 'select'` and creating custom arrays from PHP to trick the solution.

The problem is that I can see data, but I can't filter this column because of the bad implementation.

I pass to `jqGrid`, arrays from PHP with Twig.
I've needed to create two auxiliary arrays, one to have a list of ids of table `A`, and other to have values from table `C`. I related both tables by this way.

This is my code:

```
// colModel
{name:'<%identificator%>', 
    index:'table_A_id', 
    jsonmap:'table_A_id',
    editable:true,
    editrules:{ edithidden:true, required:true },
    formoptions:{ elmsuffix:' (*)' }, 
    edittype: 'select', 
    stype:'select',
    formatter: 'select',
    editoptions:{
                    value:":<%repeat%>;<%table_A_id%>:<%table_C_value%><%/repeat%>"
                }
```

With this code, I have right results inside each cell, but not right in select list for filtering.

Resuming: I need to show a value that is in table `C` from table `A`, but both tables haven't got relation, only through table `B`.

Is there any solution for that?

I use 4.0.0 version of `jqGrid`, I don't use `loadonce` attribute.

Comment: You wrote: "I can't filter this column because of the bad implementation". You should describe the problem more clear, if it's one of your main problems. Another unclear things: How many total rows of data exist in table 'A'? If you the number of rows not so large (<1000 or <10000) then you can use `loadonce: true` scenario and you will get solution without writing an additional code. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: Hi @Oleg, thank you for your fast response. My table has 3636 rows. I use 4.0.0 version.

Comment: which web browser is your main browser? Which other web browsers you support? The problem is that version 4.0.0 is dead since a long time. Moreover you didn't described which problem you have and didn't posted any code. You even didn't wrote, whether you use `loadonce: true` or not. **You should describe your problem more clear.**

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry for the inconvenience. If you need anythin else, tell me. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! The statement **"I can't filter this column because of the bad implementation"** is still unclear. What is bad implemented? What do you tried? What you expect and what you get? Do you try to use `filterToolbar`? Which options of the method you use? You can try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) to see the performance of local filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution was so particular I think:

I passed the data to jqGrid through JSON by the following way:

```
    // This is data from Table A(id, name, b_id)
    {
        "page":"1",
        "total":122,
        "records":3635,
        "rows":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"example",
            "b_id":8
        },
        { 
            "id":2,
            "name":"example2",
            "b_id":19
        }]
    }
```

So I wasn't able to relate table A and C, but finally I did it in PHP using model relations:

```
// This is data from Table A(id, name, b_id) with relations
{
    "page":"1",
    "total":122,
    "records":3635,
    "rows":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"example",
        "b_id":8,
        "relations":{
            "relation":{
                "id":200,"name":"Pepe", "id_c":22
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "id":2,
        "name":"example2",
        "b_id":19,
        "relations":{
            "relation":{
                "id":356,"name":"Jose", "id_c":45
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

And jqGrid automatically understood it, putting right values into `index` and `jsonmap` :

```
    colModel:[ ...
, {
    name:'Title',
    index:'relation.id_c',
    jsonmap:'relations.relation.id_c',
    width: 40, editable:false
    stype:'select', formatter:'select',
    editoptions:{
        value:"ids_C_table:values_C_table"
    }
}
...]
```

With this implementation, I get that I need. Cells show right data and filters work perfectly.

Hope it helps someone!